# JMeter JDBC manual commit

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter, mariadb, commit

I'm using JMeter to do some load testing, and need to run a test which inserts a few thousand records. Part of the requirement is that it should not commit each individual update, but only commit every thousand records. Seems pretty straightforward, but I cannot find any examples or documentation explaining how to do a manual commit in JMeter, and I can't get it to work.

I've got it set up to read a few entries from a csv file, plus a counter variable for an incrementing ID field. If auto commit is enabled, that works fine.
When I disable auto commit, nothing gets committed -- as you'd expect. But how DO I get it committed? I can't even get it to commit every update without auto commit, let alone a specified rate.

- I tried adding a JDBC post processor with a commit statement and/or
  commit query type, on the same DB connection pool, only one thread on
  that pool and in the test, but that doesn't work.
- Tried doing the same as a separate JDBC request, that didn't work either.
- Tried adding the commit to my update statement itself, no luck.
- Tried changing transaction isolation, but none of those values seem to make
  a difference.
- Tried opening a transaction with a pre-processor or a
  request or within the existing request, but that also hasn't helped.

I assume my problem might be that the commit is going into a separate transaction from the actual update statements...but I can't find any way to change that...

Comment: Sorry, had some issues with the DB and had to wait for the admin to return from vacation. I have tried configuring as shown in the screenshots, but I'm still getting the same result. No new records get added in the DB...

Comment: Alright, it seems I've gotten it working, gave the mariadb connector another shot instead of the mysql one and that seems to have done it, at least on the newer jmeter version. The older versions still don't work...which might be a bit of an issue as I'm not sure the newer ones are corporate approved, but I'll leave that issue to management ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

- Add a [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) with Query Type set to AutoCommit(false)
- Put your JDBC Requests as you want
- Add a JDBC Request with Query Type set to Commit

Your plan should look like this:

[image: Overview and config]

Fist set autocommit to false:

[image: set autocommit to false]

Then call your update queries:

[image: your SQL queries]

Finally commit:

[image: commit]

Reset autocommit to true:

[image: reset autocommit]

If this does not work, I suggest you report an issue to JMeter.

Comment: No luck...if it is a JMeter issue, it's a long-running one. We had JMeter 3.2 installed, which I was using originally, with mysql connector version 5.1.27, both of which are pretty old. So I upgraded to the latest -- jmeter 5.3 with mysql connector 8.0.21, then I noticed there's also a dedicated mariadb connector now so I tried that too (version 2.6.2)...but had the same issue with every combination of these. Kinda doubt that a Jmeter bug on something so basic has been unnoticed for this long...I expect it's a 'not supported in this configuration' issue...but I'll check with jmeter folks

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your test plan or run in JMeter 5.X: Menu Tools > Generate Schematic Overview. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer based on what you sent to user mailing list